# by compiling commons-io to my project proguard doesn't allow to create apk?

Tags: android, apache-commons-io

I compile Commons-io package to my android project.
when I want to create my project apk file it has problem with proguard!
what's the progaurd-rule for ignoring this package?

> compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

error is:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users***\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users***.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-io\1.3.2\b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5\commons-io-1.3.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [org/a/a/a/a.class == commons-io-1.3.2.jar:org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.class]))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Zip Entry after Gradle Plugin v0.13.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059838/duplicate-zip-entry-after-gradle-plugin-v0-13-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had the same issue. In my case I hadn't done a build for a few
>   months, and found that the dependency compile
>   'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2' is no longer valid (though I
>   guess the jars were still in my local repository).
>
> Once I changed it to compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2', proGuard
>   ran fine.

Source: [CjS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059838/duplicate-zip-entry-after-gradle-plugin-v0-13-1)